# set value of field from internal object javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

i have a class called light that loads its state by ajax:

```
function Light(name, channel, type, state) {
this.name = name;
this.channel;
this.type=type;
this.state = state;   //0=off  1=on
this.turnOn = function () {
    this.state = 1;
    $('#luce-' + name).attr('src', controlImagePath + '' + type + '100.png');
}
this.turnOff = function () {
    this.state = 0;
    $('#luce-' + name).attr('src', controlImagePath + '' + type + '00.png');
}
this.toggle = function () {
    if (this.state == 0) this.turnOn();
    else this.turnOff();
}
this.checkState = function () {
    var result;
    $.jsonp({
        callback: "callback",
        url: 'http://' + serverAddress + ':' + serverPort + '/GetChannelValueAsJsonp?channelName=' + channel + '&callback=?',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data > 0) {
                 this.turnOn();
            } else {
                 this.turnOff();
            }
        },
        error: function (xOptions, textStatus) {
            console.log("error");               
        }
    });
}
```

}

It keeps giving error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'turnOn'
```

And i suspect it is because of the success function that is overriding the Light scope. How do i refer to an object from another function scope?
IE in Java i would do Light.this.turnOn()... How to do this is javascript?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside a XHR callback function refers to the jQuery / XHR object. You have to save the `this` keyword in a variable:

```
this.checkState = function () {
    var result;
    var $this = this;  //Saving `this`
    $.jsonp({
        callback: "callback",
        url: 'http://' + serverAddress + ':' + serverPort + '/GetChannelValueAsJsonp?channelName=' + channel + '&callback=?',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data > 0) {
                 $this.turnOn(); //Referring to `this` through $this`
            } else {
                 $this.turnOff();
            }
        },
        error: function (xOptions, textStatus) {
            console.log("error");               
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew that this was totally incorrect but still not able to find the way!

Comment: @andreapier I have used a random variable name, `$this`. It should be defined as `this`, **not** `$(this)`.

Comment: Yes, i know, I was referring to what i wrote before.